Different axial and moment reactions when using different steel sections in STAAD
I am a student currently learning how to use STAAD. Im currently doing a frame analysis under different gravity loadings. I'm just wondering why is it that different steel sections have different reactions when applied to the same loading in STAAD. Selfweight is not included in the loadings. When I compared STAAD results against other software (say ftool) and manual computation, I could duplicate these results only when I used W4x13.
The problem is I was tasked to design the frame based on the axial and moment reactions of the members. My approach was to first see what their initial reactions would be without any steel section attached. However, this was impossible to do because there must be a section property for STAAD to analyze a frame. Hence, I used W4x13 as a placeholder section. After obtaining the internal reactions could I only choose which steel section is appropriate for each member. However, once I managed to assign the steel section that I chose, I found out that the different steel members had a different internal reaction to what there were originally. Why is it so?
For reference, the frame looks like this: https://ibb.co/KmPCPww

This could happen if STADD includes nonlinear large deflection effects (2nd order analysis)
